# how can i download a SSL client certificate programatically

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I want to make a rest call to an external api but it is giving SSL cert exception. One way to fix the issue was

1. Go to Browser
2. Download the CRT file
3. use keytool to generate keystore
4. Include that in my Java project
5. Use that to make a call

However is it possible to write a Java program to download the CRT, convert to keystore and use it to make the call all programatically. If i just give the website name can it extract the crt file programatically?

Comment: Have you considered using a headless browser such as selenium or puppeteer to download the crt file?

Comment: I haven't considered that. will look in to it.

Comment: @oortcloud_domicile have you resolved your need? if so how? I'm having the exact same problem to solve now.